# Problema em URL com Barra /

Tags: laravel, url, htaccess

No Laravel é muito comum usar URL amigáveis e também muito fácil de usar. O sistema já está pronto para isso.

No entanto, me surge um problema que até agora não dei importância. E agora eu quero saber o motivo disso.

Eu tenho uma rota simples para todas as minhas páginas:

```
Route::controller('/', 'FrontendController');
```

Depois no **FrontendController.php** tenho a chamada das minhas páginas:

```
public function getProdutos(){ }
public function getServicos(){ }
public function getDownload(){ }
```

Então se eu digitar:

> http://localhost/projeto/produtos 
>   http://www.dominio.com.br/produtos

Entra na página normalmente.

Mas se eu digito:

> http://localhost/projeto/produtos/ 
>   http://www.dominio.com.br/produtos/

Ele não entra e redireciona para:

> http://localhost/produtos 
>   NOT FOUND

O problema é quando coloca essa `/` no final. Sem barra funciona.

### .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

### HomeController.php

```
# Contato
public function getContato(){
    return view('frontend.contato');
}

# Trabalhe Conosco
public function getTrabalheConosco(){
    return view('frontend.trabalhe');
}

# Serviços
public function getServicos(){
    return view('frontend.servicos');
}

# Quem Somos
public function getQuemSomos(){
    return view('frontend.agencia');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao invés de:

```
Route::controller('/', 'FrontendController');
```

Faça isto:

```
Route::controller('', 'FrontendController');
```

Na documentação não existe a indicação do slash dentro do parâmetro no prefixo (no começo da string), portanto se for a root deve ser vazio.

Também note que você não pode usar letra maiúscula nos métodos, exceto na primeira letra, ou seja troque isto (pois no Laravel é tudo case-sensitive):

- `public function getTrabalheConosco(){` e `public function getQuemSomos(){`

Por isto:

- `public function getTrabalheconosco(){` e `public function getQuemsomos(){`

Testei no **Laravel5** e funcionou tanto com slash `/` quanto sem, se o problema ainda existir pode ser que você não esteja usando a pasta `public` como `root` conforme você fez na outra resposta.

A situação de redirecionar as requisições com .htaccess para `public` até funciona, mas como o Laravel não foi projeto pra funcionar assim então talvez isto seja um efeito colateral.

Note que se você esta em um ambiente de desenvolvimento você pode preferir usar o `server.php` que é um script pra ser rodado como [servidor stand-alone do php](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php).

A linha de comando pra executar ele é esta:

```
php -S localhost:8000 server.php
```

O servidor será acessivel na porta 8000, você pode trocar ela facilmente, mas note que a porta 80 as vezes pode estar em uso (como no Apache já pré-instalado em algumas distros baseadas em linux ou no Windows as vezes pelo IIS ou Skype).

Se está usando Windows pra facilitar você pode criar um `.bat` (e o caminho do php **não** estiver na *variável de ambiente* `PATH`) na pasta do seu projeto:

```
@echo off
set PHP_BIN="C:\wamp\php\php.exe"
set PHP_INI="C:\wamp\php\php.ini"

%PHP_BIN% -S localhost:8000 -c %PHP_INI% server.php
```

Execute ele e pra finalizar o servidor basta clicar <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> na tela do CMD aberta (ou simplesmente clicar em fechar).

Note tambem que simular o teste eu tenho dois arquivos, um chamado Controller.php  e um chamado HomeController.php, o segundo estende de Controller.php e não de BaseController.php, assim:

- Controller.php

  ```
  <?php

  namespace App\Http\Controllers;

  use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
  use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
  use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
  use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;

  abstract class Controller extends BaseController
  {
      use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
  }
  ```
- HomeController.php

  ```
  <?php

  namespace App\Http\Controllers;

  use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

  class HomeController extends Controller
  {
      # Contato
      public function getContato(){
          return ('frontend.contato');
      }

      # Trabalhe Conosco
      public function getTrabalheconosco(){
          return ('frontend.trabalhe');
      }

      # Serviços
      public function getServicos(){
          return ('frontend.servicos');
      }

      # Quem Somos
      public function getQuemsomos(){
          return ('frontend.agencia');
      }
  }
  ```
- routes.php:

  ```
  <?php

  Route::get('/', function () {
      return view('welcome');
  });

  Route::controller('', 'HomeController');
  ```

Comment: o problema é que o usuário ainda pode inserir a barra diretamente no final da url.

Comment: @DanielOmine Até aonde entendi é exatamente o que o AP quer. Quer que o seja acessivel com barra e sem barra no final.

Answer (score 1):

Defina a diretiva *RewriteBase*

```
RewriteBase /
```

Modifique a regra de trailing slash:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

Apenas foi removido a barra em `/$1` pois já temos definida a `RewriteBase`

Observação: remova uma linha duplicada

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Não precisa ter duas linhas iguais a essa. Note que é uma mera observação e não tem relação com o contexto da sua pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Amigão, manda seu controller para a gente ver.

Pode ser que isso ocorra, pq vc tem um overload com e sem parametro, ai quando vc usa o / no final, ele entende que é o metodo com parametro.

Da uma olhada se é isso mesmo, qlq coisa, mande o controller com as assinaturas para que possamos analisar.

Comment: Não tem nada no controller, só as funções. Vou postar.

Comment: se tem as funções, então tem algo SIM no controller, foi isso que pedi :-|