# Retirar "/" barra do final da url com htaccess

Tags: htaccess, url

Gostaria que minha *Url* funcionasse tanto com a "/" no final quanto sem ela via `htacces` fiz assim

## URL AMIGAVEIS

```
#aqui ignoramos o uso de barra no final
RewriteRule ^home$ index.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^sobre(.*)(/|)$ sobre.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^agenda(.*)(/|)$ agenda.php [NC,L]
#RewriteRule ^agenda/([^/]*)(.*)(/|)$ /curso.php?id=3&nome=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^agenda/([a-z0-9-]+)-([0-9]+)/?$ curso.php?id=$2&curso=$1 [NC]
```

O problema é que dessa maneira ele ignora os parâmetros passados na Url.

Como posso fazer ?

Comment: Pergunta similar a essa: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/105708/4793. É para Laravel, porém, a resposta que postei lá é adequada tanto para laravel quanto para qualquer outro uso.

Comment: você está utilizando algum framework ou o sitema é estruturado?